# How to display the DataFrame information in your Streamlit app instead of printing it to the console

Tags: python, pandas, buffer, streamlit

*# I'm attempting to display the output of df.info() within a Streamlit application, but the app consistently displays 'None'.

## *

I've tried modifying the default buffer and capturing the output, but the app continues to show 'None'. How can I effectively display the DataFrame information within the Streamlit application?

i try to use this code to capture the output

```
buffer=io.StringIO()
df.info(buf=buffer)
st.write(buffer.get_value())
```

but it view none instead of the expected dataframe information

Comment: If `df` is the dataframe you're trying to display, you should be able to do `st.write(df)` to display it